# Добавить картинку на кнопку JavaFX

Tags: javafx, button

Каким образом на элемент JavaFX Button можно добавить картинку?

Answer (score 3):

Кнопка с текстом и иконкой

```
Image imageOk = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("ok.png"));
Button buttonOk = new Button("OK", new ImageView(imageOk));
```

Comment: Ваш способ помог

Answer (score 3):

Еще можно из картинки сделать кнопку :

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image("path/to/img"));
image.setOnAction(e -> {...});
image.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {...});
image.setOnMouseMove(e -> {...});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 buttonOk.graphicProperty().setValue(new ImageView(imageOk));
```

также подходит